# Trouble with Jasmine and Karma with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, karma-jasmine

This is my first time testing an app and it's a bit of a headache. I have set up a testing enviroment. My `index.html` for jasmine within my test folder looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <script src="../public/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/AppView.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/FormLoanView.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/FormLoanModel.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/ResponseLoanModel.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/ResultLoanView.js"></script>

    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="spec/test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
(function () {
describe('Form Model', function() {

  describe('when instantiated', function() {

    it('should exhibit attributes', function() {
      var formModel = new FormLoanModel({});
      console.log(formModel)
      expect(formModel.get("Annual Income"))
        .toEqual("");
    });

  });

});
})();
```

When opening my `index.html` I get the following message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So it looks like its running my test. After opening chrome developer tools, I get the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
```

So I realized jQuery and Backbone are not being loaded into the test. I came to learn that Karma helps us automate a lot of this. After using Yeoman to set up karma. I made edits to my karma.conf.js which now looks like this:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2015-07-12 using
// generator-karma 1.0.0

module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    // as well as any additional frameworks (requirejs/chai/sinon/...)
    frameworks: [
      "jasmine"
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [ "../lib/*.js","../public/js/*.js","./spec/*.js"
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      "Chrome"
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
      "karma-jasmine"
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

The files I added were libraries, my backbone modules, and my Jasmine tests. After typing `karma start` I get the following success screen at the local server indicated by the terminal:

```
Karma v0.12.37 - connected
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.2) is idle
```

So finally at this point I was hoping for `index.html` after refresh would correctly run my test, but it's not. It is still warning my about its lack of knowledge of backbone and jQuery. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

**File Strucutre**

```
ROOT
-----lib
--------------backbone.js
--------------underscore.js
--------------jquery-1.11.3.js
-----public
--------------js
---------------------*backbone modules*
-----test
--------------spec
----------------------test.js
--------------index.html
--------------karma.conf.js
```

Comment: Where is backbone.js located exactly? Did you try explicitly writing the file path into the files array of the karma.config file? Maybe your glob patterns are off, and they are not matching the necessary files, so they arenot included.

Comment: So I am following the process correctly? And this isn an issue with paths?

Comment: I'm guessing that it **is** actually an issue with paths. Where are the js files of backbone located in your file system?

Comment: @doldt I added my project directory.

Comment: That seems to correspond to your file paths... When you open the developer console in Chrome (in which you're running the tests!), can you find backbone.js in the Sources tab of dev tools?

Comment: I was running karma start from my project directory. After running it in my test folder, I have found a new issue, which is likely what is holding me back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372836/cant-install-karma-phantomjs-and-karma-jasmine

Answer (score 0):

The 'basePath' and 'files' attributes of your Karma config work together to serve up the necessary files in the browser for the testing environment.

The base path will be evaluated from the working directory that Karma is run from, so if you run it in the root dir of your project, then '../libs/*.js' will not be a matching path for your bower_component javascript files, most likely.

If your static file folder tree does not start in the root dir of your project, then make sure 'basePath' points to where your static file folder tree starts.

try `../bower_components/**/*.js` or `../**/*.js` (file blob pattern style) or try adding an individual entry to "files" that points to each, i.e.,

`'../bower_components/jquery/lib/jquery.min.js',
'../bower_components/jquery/lib/backbone.min.js'`

etc, of course, making these entries point to the real locations.  I'm guessing it's just this file path issue that's preventing them from being found, and therefore Karma's testing server is not serving them to the browser.